# How to change backend technology iteratively?

Tags: node.js, grails, upgrade, microservices

**Background**

Our backend is currently written in **Grails**. We would like to change the backend to **NodeJs**. We would like to execute the change in small iterations. We deploy everything on **AWS**.

**Question**

How to change the technology from Grails to NodeJs iteratively?

**My opinion**

Although we don't use Microservice Architecture (and none of us has any experience with it) I personally would:

1. build a NodeJs server before our Grails server (something like a [Gateway API](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-API-gateway) maybe?)
2. at first the NodeJs would just pass requests/responses to/from Grails
3. then we would move other functionality from Grails (request logging, validations, ...) until we moved everything needed. (Maybe we keep something on Grails but most of the logic should end up on NodeJs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have done a successful migration from Ruby & Rails to API Gateway & Lambda based Microservices written in NodeJS. The same architecture you can use if you prefer NodeJS server (Without Microservices) or using Docker Containers Cluster with ECS.

- Setup CloudFront as a Proxy which will be getting all the HTTP traffic to your application domain (You can map the DNS to CloudFront CName)
- In CloudFront you can add the current Grails Application as the default origin and behavior which makes your application works as it is same as today.
- Then you can setup your Microservices Architecture with API Gateway and Lambda or NodeJS Web Server or Docker Container Cluster with ECS seperately. (Note that if you use a Relational Database like MySQL, it also requires to do proper placement of new server code in Lambda, WebServer or Containers so that it can access the Database)
- Afterwards, you can write the new feature logic and override one http subpath at a time from CloudFront pointing to the new application.

Following diagram shows the architecture in high-level.
[image]

Note: In the diagram, it uses DynamoDB for new Microservices and in the migration phase, you can also connect to the current Database with proper VPC, Subnet and Server placement.

In Addition you gets the benefits from CloudFront CDN in caching static assets to improve application performance and also you will be able to terminate the SSL handhshake in CloudFront with free SSL Certificates issued by Amazon.

Comment: Ashan, I will accept your solution as it basically helps me to leave the app untouched and literally makes the iterative change possible. Just another question, did you draw the diagram or is it an AWS one?

Comment: I draw the diagram few days back for a serverless training session I conducted.

Comment: I was thinking, what would you recommend us if we wanted to first do **request validation** in NodeJs. After validation we would pass the requests to Grails. Would you recommend the same approach as in your answer?

Comment: When you say request validation in NodeJS, is it to have a seperate NodeJS server? API Gateway Lambda(NodeJS) proxy? Payload validations self like format, types & etc? Payload validations connect with a database?

Comment: We would like to make the NodeJS an API Gateway - logging, validation of the request format, routing requests to other internal nodes (servers) (e.g. Grails, other nodejs, etc. ...)

Comment: request format validations can be done at API Gateway using Mapping Templates http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
If you need to proxy messages to internal servers and do validations, logging then you can use a Lambda for it, where Lambda will invoke the internal nodes

Comment: I still don't get it. I just scarcely know what are lambdas good for. Would you know how to do this without lambdas and AWS API Gateway?

Comment: You can replace API Gateway and Lambda and instead point your NodeJS server to CloudFront as a Proxy endpoint. Why I encourage to use API Gateway Lambda is still you can choose NodeJS code, lower cost of ownership and also gets High Availability, Scalability and Fault Tolerance naturally by the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is definitely possible. But I'd take another one and try using microservices. Then you will move parts of your code one by one to little cute microservices and eventually have microservice architecture. I like this approach because it allows very fast switching... Of everything. You can build your microservices with Java, Node, Go - everything you want. And if you suddenly discover that node.js is not up to your expectations (for example, if you have hardcore math modules) - just throw this microservice out and quickly impliment it in any other language and framework. The most important part is defining communication architecture. REST API is already a thing of the past and you will possibly want to use some message broker like RabbitMQ.

Comment: Interesting opinion Jehy, thank you. Are you suggesting that our Grails server becomes an API Gateway and forwards logic to other services? By saying REST has its days over, do you mean just for communication among the microservices?

Comment: Yeah, exactly this. This way you can make painless iterative migration.